# What does a question mark ("?") mean in Picard metrics files when I expect a number (integer, float, etc.)

Tags: picard

Does anyone know what conditions must be true for Picard to put a `?` where I expect a number?

Here is an example from the output of the tool [`CollectWgsMetrics`](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360036804671-CollectWgsMetrics-Picard-):

```
❯ cat sample.wgs_metrics.txt | head -n8 | tail -n2 | verticalize | grep FOLD
FOLD_80_BASE_PENALTY    1.33476
FOLD_90_BASE_PENALTY    2.288159
FOLD_95_BASE_PENALTY    ?
```

Code searching ([link](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Abroadinstitute%2Fpicard%20%5C%22%3F%5C%22&type=code)) didn't reveal anything, and googling isn't returning anything obvious either.

---

*[Verticalize is a little CLI tool I've forever been using by Pierre Lindenbaum: [`verticalize`](https://github.com/lindenb/verticalize). Easy to compile and I toss it in my `~/bin` every time I get a new computer.]*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Picard (actually HtsJdk) uses a [formatting class](https://github.com/samtools/htsjdk/blob/master/src/main/java/htsjdk/samtools/util/FormatUtil.java) (via the [MetricsFile](https://github.com/samtools/htsjdk/blob/master/src/main/java/htsjdk/samtools/metrics/MetricsFile.java) class) that emits "?" for NaNs (and Infs).

In your case, there seems to be a division-by-zero error during the calculation of the metric (likely due to zero coverage at some small percentage of bases in your input). This resulting Nan is emitted as a "?".